# MPMediaQuery invalid value

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery, mpmediaitemcollection

I'm running an MPMediaQuery to find a song in the user's iPod library, like this:

```
MPMediaQuery *songQuery = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];

[songQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:track.title forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo]];

[songQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:track.album forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo]];

[songQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:track.artist forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo]];


*** CRASH HERE ***
if (songQuery.items.count > 0) {

    return [songQuery.items objectAtIndex:0];

}

else {

    return nil;

}
```

The app crashes and spits out:

```
'invalid value (nil) for property item_extra.title.'
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a better way to query for a song? Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line:

```
[songQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:track.title forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo]];
```

The value for `track.title` is nil. You need to do a check, such as:

```
if (track.title != nil)
{
[songQuery addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:track.title forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonEqualTo]];
}
```

Edit: I would recommend doing a check on each of the variables that you would be adding as a filter predicate to make sure they are also not nil!

Comment: Oh boy... I thought this was the obvious culprit based on the log output, so I had logged the values earlier and ensured they weren't nil. When I was sure, I changed the way I set the values and they went back to being nil at the time of query. You were absolutely right, thank you!